# How to use Observable zip with rxjava2 to get multiple responses back?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a java android app with I am using retrofit/rxjava2 to make multiple requests to my api. I want to wait until all the requests have completed then return the responses.  So far I am able to create the requests but I can not get any responses. The code only does the first request.

I used this tutorial, https://github.com/fakefacebook/Retrofit-2-with-Rxjava-multiple-request. But it still doesn't work....

```
public static void checkDB(List<String> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        //no tags to check
    } else {
        System.out.println("list is not empty");
        MyAPIendpoint apiService = RetrofitAPI.getClient().create(MyAPIendpoint.class);

        List<Observable<Bmwvehiclemain2>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String t : list) {
            requests.add(apiService.getVehByRfidtag(t));
        }

        Observable.zip(requests, new Function<Object[], List<Bmwvehiclemain2>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Bmwvehiclemain2> apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {
                List<Bmwvehiclemain2> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Object response : objects) {
                    newList.add((Bmwvehiclemain2) response);
                }
                return newList;
            }
        }).subscribe(
                new Consumer<List<Bmwvehiclemain2>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<Bmwvehiclemain2> newList) throws Exception {
                    }
                },
                new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable e) throws Exception {
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

It will only do the first request.

Comment: It would be helpful if the code was more properly formatted.

Comment: Does anyone know why this isn't working??

Comment: I would try using combineLatest with a BiFunction observer. I don't believe Zip is the best operator for this.